# Is there an alternative to ZK spreadsheet supporting copy/paste from Excel?

Tags: java, zk

ZK spreadsheet seems to have all the features I need except the support of copy/paste from Excel.

I'm looking for an open source solution in java (or client-side javascript).

Suggestions of proprietary software are welcome too.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Next version of ZK Spreadsheet which is expected to be released around early May will support copy/paste from/to Excel.